# I would like to know what's wrong with this code

Tags: java, string, if-statement, linked-list

I want to use if statement for a multiple choice with string variable...
However, I can't input an answer or letter of my choice and it just immediately outputs "Input Error" even though I haven't input anything yet...
Can I ask what's wrong with this code?

```
    System.out.println("Pick your choice: \na. Add Node\nb. Delete Node\nc. Insert Node");
    String letterChoice = scan.nextLine();

    if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
        System.out.println("Enter node value: ");
        int nodeValue = scan.nextInt();
        list.addNodes(nodeValue);
    }
    else if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
        System.out.println("Which node to delete? Node #: ");
        int thisNode = scan.nextInt();
        list.deleteNode(thisNode);
    }
    else if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
        System.out.println("Input node number: ");
        int thisNode = scan.nextInt();
        int prevNode = thisNode - 1;

        System.out.println("Input node value: ");
        int nodeValue = scan.nextInt();

        list.insertNode(nodeValue, prevNode);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Input Error");
    }
```

I couldn't find help from previous questions here unless I change my code... I don't want to, so I had to ask... Thanks...

Full Code...

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class DoublyLinkedList {


        static DNode root;
        static DNode temp;
        static DNode current;


        public void addNodes(int data){

            DNode dNode = new DNode(data);

            if(root==null){

                root = dNode;
                root.previousNode = null;
                root.nextNode = null;

            }else{

                current = root;

                while(current.nextNode!=null){

                    current = current.nextNode;

                }

                current.nextNode = dNode;
                dNode.previousNode = current;
                dNode.nextNode = null;

            }

        }

        public void insertNode(int data, int after){

            DNode dNode = new DNode(data);

            int ithNode = 1;

            current = root;

            while(ithNode != after){

                current = current.nextNode;

                ithNode++;

            }

            temp = current.nextNode;

            current.nextNode = dNode;
            dNode.nextNode = temp;
            temp.previousNode = dNode;
            dNode.previousNode = current;

        }

        public void deleteNode(int nodeNumber){

            int ithNode = 1;

            current = root;

            if(nodeNumber==1){

                root = current.nextNode;
                current.nextNode = null;
                current.previousNode = null;

            }else{

                while(ithNode != nodeNumber){

                    current = current.nextNode;

                    ithNode++;

                }

                if(current.nextNode == null){

                    current.previousNode.nextNode = null;
                    current.previousNode = null;

                }else{

                    current.previousNode.nextNode = current.nextNode;
                    current.nextNode.previousNode = current.previousNode;

                }

            }

        }

        public void print(){

            current = root;

            System.out.print("The Linked List: ");

            do{

                System.out.print(" " + current.data + " ");


                current = current.nextNode;

            }while(current!=null);

        }

        public void printBackwards(){

            current = root;

            while(current.nextNode!=null){

                current = current.nextNode;

            }

            System.out.print("Inverse: ");

            do{

                System.out.print(" " + current.data + " ");

                current = current.previousNode;

            }while(current.previousNode!=null);

            System.out.print(" " + current.data + " " );

        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

            DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            String letterChoice = "";
            int nodesNum;

            System.out.print("Input number of nodes: ");
            nodesNum = scan.nextInt();

            for(int x = 1; x <= nodesNum; x++){
                System.out.print("Input value of node #" + x + ": ");
                int value = scan.nextInt(); 
                list.addNodes(value);
            }

            list.print();


            System.out.println("Pick your choice: \na. Add Node\nb. Delete Node\nc. Insert Node");
            letterChoice = scan.nextLine();

            if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("A.")){
                System.out.println("Enter node value: ");
                int nodeValue = scan.nextInt();
                list.addNodes(nodeValue);
            }
            else if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("B.")){
                System.out.println("Which node to delete? Node #: ");
                int thisNode = scan.nextInt();
                list.deleteNode(thisNode);
            }
            else if(letterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C.")){
                System.out.println("Input node number: ");
                int thisNode = scan.nextInt();
                int prevNode = thisNode - 1;

                System.out.println("Input node value: ");
                int nodeValue = scan.nextInt();

                list.insertNode(nodeValue, prevNode);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Input Error");
            }

            list.print();
            System.out.println();
            list.printBackwards();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The number of DNodes in the Linked List is " + DNode.noOfLinkedList);


        }

    }


     class DNode {

        static int noOfLinkedList = 0;

        int data;

        DNode previousNode;
        DNode nextNode;

        DNode(int data){

            this.data = data;
            noOfLinkedList++;

        }

    }
```

Thanks for all the help, but either something's wrong with my jdk or cmd, or that nothing's helping... or maybe i'm just not making myself clear... see, this is my problem... 
[image: Image of the problem]

It runs, yes, but it just skips to the else part where it outputs "Input Error" ...

Comment: What is letterChoice?

Comment: it's a String variable... String...

Comment: You certainly have a `nextInt()` above

Comment: yeah, i mean, they are different...

Comment: letterChoice and the others with .nextInt() are different...

Comment: What is list? Can we have the full code, plz

Comment: sorry... i'll put it right away...

Comment: You code works. When I enter "a." or "b.", it does not return the error. You changed your code so that it is checking for a, not a. now

Comment: so, there's nothing wrong with my current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `Scanner#nextInt` method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine.

take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29

## QuickFix

```
System.out.print("Input number of nodes: ");
nodesNum = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine(); //this force the reading of the last newline after reading the integer...
        
...
System.out.println("Pick your choice: \na. Add Node\nb. Delete Node\nc. Insert Node");
final String letterChoice = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: i didn't... should I?

Comment: yes, that is what am explaining, nextInt is not flushing the nextline in the input stream....  add it, test it and let me know

Comment: Oh thanks, it finally worked... although i don't quite understand why...  
Thanks a lot though